# willow garage world - 2d map

Tags: navigation, mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Ros User,
is it possible to get a 2d map (basically for amcl and move base) of the willow garage environment simulated in the willow garage world?
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221126/willow-garage-world---2d-map/) by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2015-11-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

<s>The accepted answer to this thread is no longer correct.

The .pgm files at that website do not match the Gazebo world "willowgarage.world"</s>

UPDATE by @130s: As of Jan 2017 this is the right location.

The correct 2D map is "willow-2010-02-18-0.10.pgm"
found here:
/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_navigation/maps
or
https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/tree/indigo/turtlebot_navigation/maps

---

Originally posted by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) with karma: 1103 on 2017-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First thing to try can be spawn a Turtlebot with `gmapping`. Move around in Willow Garage office with `teleop` and save the resulting map with `map_server`.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-11-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on 2015-11-18**:
I was just wondering if someone else had already done the gmapping process and if the resulting map is somewhere available

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2015-11-18**:
Why would you do gmapping on a map you already have?

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2015-11-19**:
Willow Garage office is available in gazebo as a world. AFAIK, gazebo does not provide .pgm map file. Therefore you can do gmapping to have this map. But as @130s mentioned there are .pgm files for WG office in WG's website which I did not know priorly. Therefore @Rahndall can use it directly.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some generated `map` files for Willow's office are available: http://pr.willowgarage.com/data/maps/ (found via [this thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/37762/are-there-any-interesting-pgm-map-files-available-for-simulation/)).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-11-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know this is super old, but the need came up to have a very accurate map of the willowgarage.world, and using mapping seemed like it would be pretty tedious, and the map in the accepted answer was decent but has many gaps.

Using [this excellent package](https://github.com/hyfan1116/pgm_map_creator), I generated a map, [which you can download from here (google drive)](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1r4dK2rchrglry0M1LmoVmRjhXQkSVZ_7?usp=sharing) if you need it.

---

Originally posted by [trevor.ablett](https://answers.ros.org/users/93692/trevor.ablett/) with karma: 11 on 2022-01-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1